# Line width Illustrator multiple lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

How do I apply width effects to multiple lines?

I've drawn two lines:

[image]

And when I select both lines and apply the width effect with the width tool, only one changes:

[image]

How do I make multiple lines be effected at once so that the custom widths are uniform?

I'm only able to get one line to change its custom width at a time. With all other effects i'm able to apply effects to multiple objects at a time.

Comment: If the width is going to be the same for multiple paths, then create the width on 1 path and duplicate that path.

Comment: For my project I have hundreds of lines in complex patterns, and I need to learn how to apply effects to multiple lines because of spacing/complexity. Any suggestions about why the width tool doesn't apply to multiple lines?

Comment: The width tool creates an anchor point on the path. That is how you're able to change the widths on both sides of the line. You can only add anchor points to the path you click on even if you have multiple paths selected. This is the same concept as the add anchor point tool.

Comment: Is there a work around for this - perhaps creating all of the anchor points in the same spot first? It's looking like applying the effect once, and then manually moving each piece to align is the only way. Seems like there should be an easier way to do this... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The width tool will only change one line at a time as far as I know. There are, however, preset stroke forms that will change all selected paths at once.**

With the select tool, select the paths you wish to change. Click the dropdown menu where it displays "Uniform" and select from there.

You can also create your own **custom width "profile" using the width tool.**

Select a path you wish to adjust. **Use the width tool** and form it the way you would like. Then, while the path is still selected, click the same dropdown I mentioned earlier (it won't say uniform anymore if you have manually adjusted the width). Then click the button labeled **"Add to Profiles"** and name your new width profile.

**Once you set your new width profile, select all your paths you wish to change and select the new profile which will change all of them at once.**